# libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: firefox, centos

While running firefox on centos . I am getting the following error. how do i resolve this?

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/ec2-user/work/software/firefox34/libxul.so:
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Comment: I am also stuck at the same place. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

try it .

yum install gtk2-2.24.23-8.el6.i686